# Iterators in event manager for game becoming invalidated upon unregister

Tags: c++, game-engine

I am writing an EventManager class for a game I am making for school.  It utilizes a double queue system for events and holds an unordered_map consisting of events types and vectors of ID's registered to respond to the particular events.  The problem I am having is that certain events (like when you click the play button for the main menu)may cause an actor to unregister events. While this is intentional it causes problems with the iterators which is not intentional. In the example where it switches from the main menu to the game it destroys all the actors(buttons and such) that are part of the main menu.  These, in turn, unregister themselves with the event manager which deletes their id from the corresponding vector stored in the unordered_map and invalidates the iterator throwing an exception at the beginning of the loop.  As such no event can cause an actor to unregister anything.  This is undesirable because some trigger objects in the game may be one time triggers at which point they need to unregister themselves from receiving more events.  Any help or ideas would be greatly appreciated.

```
    void EventManager::Flush()
    {
        Event* current;
        while (m_eventList[m_current].size() > 0)
        {
            current = m_eventList[m_current].front();
            m_eventList[m_current].pop_front();
            unordered_map<string, vector<IDTYPE>>::iterator it =  m_registeredEvents.find(current->GetType());
            if (it == m_registeredEvents.end())
                continue;
            vector<IDTYPE>* toProcessAct = &(it->second);
            vector<IDTYPE>::iterator actIt = toProcessAct->begin();
            while (actIt != toProcessAct->end())                   //this becomes invalid
            {
                Actor* temp = ACTORS->GetActor(*actIt);
                if (temp == NULL)
                    actIt = toProcessAct->erase(actIt);
                else
                {
                    actIt++;
                    temp->Process(current);              //Because this may unregister events
                }
            }
            delete current; current = 0;
        }
        Swap();
    }

void EventManager::UnregisterEvent(string Event, IDTYPE actor)
{
    unordered_map<string, vector<IDTYPE>>::iterator it = m_registeredEvents.find(Event);
    //Found
    if (it != m_registeredEvents.end())
    {
        //Find if actor is already registered
        vector<IDTYPE>::iterator actIt = it->second.begin();
        while (actIt != it->second.end())
        {
            if (actor == *actIt)
            {
                it->second.erase(actIt);
                return;
            }
            actIt++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: edit for unregister code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good way to shoot yourself in the foot

```
    Event* current;  // not the issue here but you should always initialize your variables.
    while (m_eventList[m_current].size() > 0) {
        current = m_eventList[m_current].front(); // current points the the first element
        m_eventList[m_current].pop_front(); // now the first element gets destroyed
        unordered_map<string, vector<IDTYPE>>::iterator it =  m_registeredEvents.find(current->GetType()); // its pure coincident if this works.
```

[pop_front()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/pop_front/) destroys the front element making the pointer invalid and you enter undefined behaviour. Make a copy of the record instead, then you also don't have problems with destroying it.

Further all iterators to elements after the a delete are invalid, so if your code saves iterators as a state you will get hurt, just presume all deletes makes all iterators to that or related containers invalid to be safe.

If you are running a multi-threaded program you have the further problem that other threads could change the content, use at least a mutex to protect it.

OK, now for what you actually asked for:

```
        while (actIt != toProcessAct->end()) {  // end() should update but actIt doesn't.
            Actor* temp = ACTORS->GetActor(*actIt);
            if (temp == NULL)
                actIt = toProcessAct->erase(actIt);
            else {
                actIt = temp->Process(actIt, current); // make Process return the new valid It
            }
        }
        delete current; // would fail as there is a continue higher up!!!
        current = 0; // if using C++11 use nullptr instead else NULL
```

Make Process return the new valid Iterator or toProcessAct->end() if no more are valid after actIt.

Comment: Doesn't solve the problem but still very useful as I didn't realize that pop_front actually destroyed the element I thought it just removed it from the deque.  What does this mean for elements that are on the heap and need to be deleted explicitly?

Comment: The destructor is call for the front object and it then does what it has to do.

Comment: Updated with what the OP really asked.

Answer (score 1):

One solution can be to iterate over a copy of event handlers vector, that is instead of

```
vector<IDTYPE>* toProcessAct = &(it->second);
```

write

```
vector<IDTYPE> toProcessAct = it->second;
```

(and make corresponding changes for the code to compile).
 Also probably it will be faster if you make a copy of the whole `m_registeredEvents` in the start of `Flush()`, so you won't have to copy vectors several times.

---

Another solution would be to make unregistration deferred, that is `UnregisterEvent()` instead of executing instantly would enqueue the unregistration request into separate queue and execute it later, for example at the end of `Flush()`.

Comment: That was what I initially when with and then got some exceptions about iterators being incompatible.  I see what you are saying about deferring the unregistration until later but that would mean redesigning the whole system around that one aspect which usually means there is a problem with my design elsewhere (wish I could find it though).

Comment: This might be what I have to do though...whenever an actor unregisters itself its added to an unregister list and then as the event manager iterates through it looks to see if the actor requested to be unregistered for the event via the list and calls erase updating its iterator.  I don't like it but I cant think of any other way to do it without redesigning the entire system which I don't have time for because of homework constraints.